# LINQ to XML query Where() function not returning anything

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file I would like to parse using LINQ in order to get all nodes containing the attribute `ID`. With this `ID`, the node's name, and it's grandparent's name, I would like to create an new object (of type `EveItem`) in the LINQ query.

Here is a part of my XML file to give an example of how it is constructed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Eve_App>
    <Item_Types>
        <Ore>
            <Arkonor_Category>
                <Arkonor ID="22"/>
                <Compressed_Arkonor ID="28367"/>
                <Compressed_Crimson_Arkonor ID="28385"/>
                <Compressed_Prime_Arkonor ID="28387"/>
                <Crimson_Arkonor ID="17425"/>
                <Prime_Arkonor ID="17426"/>
            </Arkonor_Category>

            <Bistot_Category>
                <Bistot ID="1223"/>
                <Compressed_Bistot ID="28388"/>
                <Compressed_Monoclinic_Bistot ID="28389"/>
                <Compressed_Triclinic_Bistot ID="28390"/>
                <Monoclinic_Bistot ID="17429"/>
                <Triclinic_Bistot ID="17428"/>
            </Bistot_Category>

            <Crokite_Category>
                <Compressed_Crokite ID="28391"/>
                <Compressed_Crystalline_Crokite ID="28392"/>
                <Compressed_Sharp_Crokite ID="28393"/>
                <Crokite ID="1225"/>
                <Crystalline_Crokite ID="17433"/>
                <Sharp_Crokite ID="17432"/>
            </Crokite_Category>

            <Dark_Ochre_Category>
                <Compressed_Dark_Ochre ID="28394"/>
                <Compressed_Obsidian_Ochre ID="28395"/>
                <Compressed_Onyx_Ochre ID="28396"/>
                <Dark_Ochre ID="1232"/>
                <Obsidian_Ochre ID="17437"/>
                <Onyx_Ochre ID="17436"/>
            </Dark_Ochre_Category>
            ...
        </Ore>

        <Ice>
            <Ice>
                <Blue_Ice ID="16264"/>
                <CLear_Icicle ID="16262"/>
                <Compressed_Blue_Ice ID="28433"/>
                <Compressed_Clear_Icicle ID="28434"/>
                <Compressed_Dark_Glitter ID="28435"/>
                <Compressed_Enriched_Clear_Icicle ID="28436"/>
                <Compressed_Gelidus ID="28437"/>
                <Compressed_Glacial_Mass ID="28438"/>
                <Compressed_Glare_Crust ID="28439"/>
                <Compressed_Krystallos ID="28440"/>
                <Compressed_Pristine_White_Glaze ID="28441"/>
                <Compressed_Smooth_Glacial_Mass ID="28442"/>
                <Compressed_Thick_Blue_Ice ID="28443"/>
                <Compressed_White_Glaze ID="28444"/>
                <Dark_Glitter ID="16267"/>
                <Enriched_Clear_Icicle ID="17978"/>
                <Gelidus ID="16268"/>
                <Glacial_Mass ID="16263"/>
                <Glare_Crust ID="16266"/>
                <Krystallos ID="16269"/>
                <Pristine_White_Glaze ID="17976"/>
                <Smooth_Glacial_Mass ID="17977"/>
                <Thick_Blue_Ice ID="17975"/>
                <White_Glaze ID="16265"/>
            </Ice>
        </Ice>
        ...
```

I have tried the following query to do what I want to do, but unfortunately, it does not work:

```
items = _xmlFile.Descendants(itemType.ToString())
                    .Where(x => x.Attribute("ID") != null)  // This part returns nothing
                    .Select(x => new EveItem(x.Name.LocalName,
                        (uint)x.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ID"), 
                        (EveItem.ItemTypes)itemType)).ToList();
```

When I debug this query in Visual Studio, I can see that `_xmlFile.Descendants(itemType.ToString())` returns the good sub tree of my XML file, but the `.Where(x => x.Attribute("ID") != null)` part of the query does not return anything (so the `.Select(..)` doesn't get executed on anything). What I am trying to get by this `Where(..)` clause is all the nodes that actually have the attribute `ID` declared in them.

What am I doing wrong in this query?

**EDIT:**

I have tried removing the `itemType.ToString()` from the call to `_xmlFile.Descendants()` and it now works, though I get ALL items that have an `ID` attribute instead of the ones that are only under the right `itemType` node (Ore, Ice, etc).

Why is that happening though? In debug, I do see that the `_xmlFile.Descendants(itemType.ToString())` call returns the right XML structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because none of your item type node (Ore, Ice, etc) have `ID` attribute. The attribute is in descendant of item type nodes, so try to add `.Descendants()` method call, like so :

```
items = _xmlFile.Descendants(itemType.ToString())
                .Descendants()  //get descendants of current item type
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("ID") != null)
                .Select(x => new EveItem(
                                x.Name.LocalName,
                                (uint)x.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ID"), 
                                (EveItem.ItemTypes)itemType
                            )
                        )
                .ToList();
```

Comment: This works. Though I still don't understand why I have to add another `.Descendants()`. Doesn't `.Descendants()` send back all elements that are a child of the node passed to it? So yeah, my Ore, Ice, etc nodes don't have any `ID` attribute, but it should still check their childs, grandchilds, etc until the leaf nodes no? That was my understanding of how the function worked anyways, am I mistaken?

Comment: No, you must be confused. Here `.Descendants(itemType.ToString())`, *descendant* is in the sense *descendant of `_xmlFile`* which name is `itemType.ToString())`.

Comment: You are indeed right. I just checked the msdn documentation and understood the difference between both function calls (with and without parameters). Thanks for pointing that out!